# Resolution of 4320x900 with TripleHead2go Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, kubuntu, display-resolution, nvidia-settings

I used to have a resolution of 4320x900 but since I upgrade nvidia to 340.76 it gives me a max resolution of 3840x1024. I cannot find the `xorg.conf` file, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution :

I add a file called `10-monitor.conf` into `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` folder with the following content :

```
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  Modeline    "4320x900" 251.07 4320 4336 4352 4480 900 903 912 934 -HSync +VSync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device "DVI-I-1"
Monitor "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
  Depth 24
Modes "4320x900_60.00" "1440x900"
Option "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes, NoVirtualSizeCheck, NoMaxPClkCheck, NoWidthAlignmentCheck, NoExtendedGpuCapabilitiesCheck"
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Rebooted and the 4320x900 resolution is back! Hope this will be helpful to somebody.

Comment: Now, you can accept it as this what it does work for you.